# Android Text View giving an error when trying to set text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have a layout with few labels and textviews which I want to update based on a action. For testing I have set up the java `MainActivity` to load the textviews I want to use on created.

Once I click a button called add, the code is executed and prints that the add button was pushed.

I also want the text area to say add for testing. Later on in the project I will change what is displayed here.

However, once I click the button the program stops. I know that the button works because the print shows up in the log.

I have looked and looked and all I can find is the `textfield.settext();` But when using this the error occurs and the program stops.

Below is my XML for the `TextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000066"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.smartshop.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android1:id="@+id/cartlist"
        android1:layout_width="289dp"
        android1:layout_height="236dp"
        android1:textColor="@color/textc" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android1:layout_width="0pt"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:background="@color/buttonc"
            android1:onClick="clkaddbutton"
            android1:text="Add Item" />
        <!-- android1:onClick="clkaddbutton" -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Space
            android1:id="@+id/space1"
            android1:layout_width="2dp"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/btnremove"
            android1:layout_width="0pt"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:background="@color/buttonc"
            android1:onClick="clkremovebutton"
            android1:text="Remove Item" />
        <!-- android1:onClick = "clkremovebutton" -->

    </LinearLayout>
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/verticalspacesize">
</View>
    <LinearLayout
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/lblsubtotal"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="3.40"
            android1:text="Sub Total"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:textColor="@color/textc" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/tvsubtotal"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="3.40"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>


<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/verticalspacesize">
</View>
    <LinearLayout
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/lbltax"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:text="Tax"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:textColor="@color/textc" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/tvtax"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/verticalspacesize">
</View>

    <LinearLayout
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/lbltotal"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:text="Total"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:textColor="@color/textc" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/tvtotal"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android1:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java code in the `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.smartshop;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button btnadd; 
    private Button btnremove;
    private TextView tfsubtotal ;
    private TextView tftax; 
    private TextView tftotal; 
         public void clkaddbutton(View view) {
             System.out.println("Add clicked");
           tfsubtotal.setText("add");
         }
        public void clkremovebutton(View view) {
         tfsubtotal.setText("Rem");
         }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnremove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnremove);
        btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        tfsubtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsubtotal);
        if(tfsubtotal != null){
        System.out.println("The subtotal edittext was created");
        tfsubtotal.setText("test" );
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The textview is null");
        }
        //tfsubtotal.setText("Google is your friend." );
        tftax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtax);
        tftotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtotal);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I know that the problem is on the `tfsubtotal.setText("add");` line because I have tested without it and everything works.

I have also tried to use edit text boxes instead of textviews but I get the same error.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Below is the android log:

```
05-22 22:37:21.251: I/System.out(1693): The subtotal edittext was created
05-22 22:37:21.251: D/AndroidRuntime(1693): Shutting down VM
05-22 22:37:21.261: W/dalvikvm(1693): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2accba8)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693): Process: com.example.smartshop, PID: 1693
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smartshop/com.example.smartshop.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at com.example.smartshop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-22 22:37:21.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1693):     ... 11 more
05-22 22:37:23.451: I/Process(1693): Sending signal. PID: 1693 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the layout xml name, `activity_main` or `fragment_main`?

Comment: But where are you calling `clkbuttonadd()` and the other method

Comment: And post the stack trace here?

Comment: The xml is called fragment_main, the click is being called in a different part of the xml file <Button
                android1:id="@+id/btnadd"
                android1:layout_width="0pt"
                android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android1:layout_weight="1"
                android1:background="@color/buttonc"
                android1:onClick="clkaddbutton"
                android1:text="Add Item" />

Comment: Here is the log with the stack trace

Comment: Please, post full xml and activity code.

Comment: I have posted the full xml and activity

Comment: I can't see any click handles and conclude that the promlem is in this line `//tfsubtotal.setText("Google is your friend." );` when uncommented, right?

Comment: Try to make sure `tfsubtotal` is ready to be used, not in null state yet `if (tfsubtotal != null) ...`

Comment: Are you sure the xml you posted here is activity_main.xml?

Comment: Yes, that line is a problem, along with the line tfsubtotal.setText("add"); which is in the clkaddbutton method
the clkaddbutton method is what is executed when the button is clicked, but both of them cause the same error since they are both doing the same thing.

Comment: I added a null check, and the tfsubtotal is null, I am going to update the code.  But I don't understand why it would be null.  
My xml is in a Fragment_Main, not the mainActivity, but since the button click works I did not think that was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Button btnadd; 
private Button btnremove;
private TextView tfsubtotal ;
private TextView tftax; 
private TextView tftotal; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    System.out.println("The subtotal edittext was created");
    //tfsubtotal.setText("Google is your friend." );
    tftax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtax);
    TextView tfsubtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsubtotal);
    tftotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtotal);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
        .commit();
    }
}
public void clkaddbutton(View view) {
        // tfsubtotal.
       System.out.println("Add clicked");
       tfsubtotal.setText("add");
     }
    public void clkremovebutton(View view) {
     tfsubtotal.setText("Rem");
     }
```

**OR**

**Why not just do simply like this :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    Button btnRemove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnremove);
    tfsubtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsubtotal);
    System.out.println("The subtotal edittext was created");
    //tfsubtotal.setText("Google is your friend." );
    tftax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtax);
    tftotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtotal);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
        .commit();
    }

    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    System.out.println("Add clicked");
    tfsubtotal.setText("add");

    }

    });

    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    System.out.println("Add clicked");
    tfsubtotal.setText("Rem");

    }

    });

}
```